# AWS Route 53 subdomain connected to AWS Lightsail suddenly fails to resolve

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

About a few weeks ago, I linked my Lightsail Wordpress server to `example.mysite.com` using AWS Route 53.

Today, I added a security certificate by using `sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool`. After doing this, the site worked fine and now I had a security certificate.

Then about 5 minutes later, I noticed that visiting `example.mysite.com` would return a browser error (`This site can’t be reached`). Fortunately, visiting the server IP would still work.

I tried running `sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool` again, but it complains that `example.mysite.com` doesn't redirect to the server IP, even though Amazon Route53 says so.

Interestingly, all my other AWS Route53 A Records that aren't connected to AWS Lightsail work fine.

I still tried reaching `example.mysite.com` for 10 minutes, but it didn't work. I tried looking up this error online but that also didn't return anything I needed. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Apparently, this issue magically fixed itself. I will not close this question yet in case it decides to cause problems later.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to have been some sort of glitch (which was out of my control).

Occasionally, `example.mysite.com` will not work, but reloading the page usually fixes it.